# Responsive Slider that supports image map and has a lot of transition

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive-design, imagemap, responsive-slides

So Nivo Slider is Responsive but does not support image maps.

Sliderman supports image map but is not responsive.

Is there any slider that fits my needs?

Comment: Did you find a slider that fit your needs?

Comment: @Summit Nope still on the search for the perfect slider